# Getting the previous page GET parameters in PHP

Tags: php, http, get

I have a range of similar pages that have a URL along the lines of `www.mydomain.com/group?id=1`.

From each of these pages there is a form that posts it's values to the server. I need to work out what the `id` of the group was when the form is posted. I'm aware of being able to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and then maybe I could use a regex to get the `id`. However, I wondered if there was anything in PHP that would allow you to get the previous $_GET variables?

Alternatively, do people think it is a much better idea to store the current group id as a session variable?

Comment: Why arent you just passing the id again as part of the URL for your form `action`?

Comment: Because that would be an incredibly easy way to hack the form?

Comment: @alex : and trusting that the user hasn't mangled the referer is any better?

Comment: @MarcB this is why I've opted for using session variables.

Comment: @alex: i didnt realize the id was sensitive info, i would think that since youre passing it via get on other pages that simple validation + standard CSRF prevention would be enough.

Comment: @prodigitalson the id in the GET is checked with the logged in user to see if they should have access on a group page load. So maybe if I included the id in the action, then checked on the server when the form is posted I could see whether the form had been tampered with? The worst they could do is post to another group they have access to right?

Comment: @alex: well as far as the "worst case" yes that was my thought :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Session is the way to go to . Store them and get the groups on every other page, using session . This is a proper way.

---

Despite, it is also possible to make $_GET available for every page. Using two ways (AFAIK).

1. Create the exact same URL String with the parameters and send them along, as you are redirecting from page to page.

   - Or use functions like [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get only the query string and pass them along
2. Use Session to back up the $_GET and reassign it to $_GET on every page. Put the below snippet or every page you redirect to.

   ```
   if(isset($_SESSION['GET_BACKUP']) { //Check if there was a backup before
        $_GET = $_SESSION['GET_BACKUP'];  //if yes use it
   }

   if(isset($_GET) && count($_GET)) { //if not and GET value is sent
        $_SESSION['GET_BACKUP'] = $_GET; //backup it
   }
   // Now use the get as you used to via $_GET
   ```

   Following this way, you will not get an attached data in the URL, which might be undesirable.

---

#### Update:

In case you are going with the second option, you should remember that the solution I provided is an *demo* and will not fit for more than one `$_GET` group. For multiple pages and storing their SESSIONS, you have to define separate keys to identify the backup. Kinda like

```
$_SESSION['mypage.php']['GET_BACKUP'] = $_GET;
```

Comment: What would happen if a user had two 'group' pages open and he submitted to the group he'd opened first? Surely the $_SESSION would have the second groups id?

Comment: @Alex, there was an typo in the update. I meant to say `will not fit for more than one $_GET group.` Sorry

Answer (score 2):

A multi-page form is commonly termed a 'wizard'. If the following pages depend on subsequent values the most common solution is to store the form-pieces in `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 1):

> I wondered if there was anything in PHP that would allow you to get the previous $_GET variables

There isn't. However, you can use SESSION to save all GET parameters manually.

```
//first page
$_SESSION["pages"][] = $_GET;

//second page, before setting GET parameters for current page
$last = count($_SESSION["pages"]) - 1;
if ($_SESSION["pages"][$last]["whatever"]) {

}
```